# How do I flush a 'RandomAccessFile' (java)?

Tags: java, flush

I'm using RandomAccessFile in java:

```
file = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "rw");
...
file.writeBytes(...);
```

How can I ensure that this data is flushed to the Operating System?  There is no file.flush() method.  (Note that I don't actually expect it to be physically written, I'm content with it being flushed to the operating system, so that the data will survive a tomcat crash but not necessarily an unexpected server power loss).

I'm using tomcat6 on Linux.

Comment: How can a `RandomAccessFile` be flushed only to OS not necessarily to physical disk?

Comment: The data is written to the disk cache pages, and therefore is immediately visible to other processes, and also will survive a crash of the process that wrote the data, but is not written to disk and therefore would not survive e.g. a sudden power loss.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The only classes that provide a `.flush()` method are those that actually maintain their own buffers.  As `java.io.RandomAccessFile` does not itself maintain a buffer, it does not need to be flushed.

Comment: Jim Yingst says: "I should add that in my experience, RandomAccessFile is usually pretty slow for most applications. It's a jack-of-all-trades class; it does a lot of different things, but isn't particularly good at anyof them. You can usually create a combination of streams that does what you want with greater efficiency."

Comment: @TimCooper Your comment is for the OP, not this answer, right?

Answer (score 6):

Have a look carefully at RandomAccessFile constructor javadoc:

The "rws" and "rwd" modes work much like the force(boolean) method of the FileChannel class, passing arguments of true and false, respectively, except that they always apply to every I/O operation and are therefore often more efficient. If the file resides on a local storage device then when an invocation of a method of this class returns **it is guaranteed that all changes made to the file by that invocation will have been written to that device**. This is useful for ensuring that critical information is not lost in the event of a system crash. If the file does not reside on a local device then no such guarantee is made.

Comment: With all due respect, so, what is your point? You mean anyone should use `rws` or `rwd` for being guaranteed v`flushing`v? Then what is `rw` for?

Comment: @JinKwon **R**ead **W**rite

Answer (score 5):

You can use `getFD().sync()` method.

Comment: The asker specifically stated they don't need the data physically written to disk, which is essentially what the sync() method is for.

Comment: @davmac I'd rather to ask you than ask to OP. How can a `RandomAccessFile` be flushed only to OS not necessarily to physical disk?

Comment: @JinKwon as per Jonathan Callen's answer - you don't need to flush a `RandomAccessFile`. Every time you write to it, the data you write is transferred to the OS immediately.

Answer (score 3):

here's what i do in my app:

```
rf.close();
rf = new RandomAccessFile("mydata", "rw");
```

this is give 3-4times gain in performance
compared to getFd().sync() and 5-7 times compared to "rws' mode

deoes exactly what the original question proposed: passes
on unsaved data to the OS and out of JVM. Doesn't physically
write to disk, and therefore introduces no annoying delays

Comment: If you simply delete those two lines, nothing will change, except that Java needs less garbage collection and the file system cache might become more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I reached here with the very same curiosity.

And I really can't figure what **need to flush on OS and not necessarily need to flush to Disk** part means.

In my opinion,

The best thing matches to the concept of a ***managed flushing*** is [`getFD().sync()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileDescriptor.html#sync--), as @AVD said,

```
try(RandomAccessFile raw = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw")) {
    raw.write...
    raw.write...
    raw.getFD().sync();
    raw.wirte...
}
```

which looks like, by its documentation, it works very much like what [FileChannel#force(boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#force-boolean-) does with `true`.

Now `"rws"` and `"rwd"` are look like they work as if specifying [`StandardOpenOption#SYNC`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html#SYNC) and [`StandardOpenOption#DSYNC`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html#DSYNC) respectively while a `FileChannel` is [`open`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#open-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-).

```
try(RandomAccessFile raw = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rws")) {
    raw.write...
    raw.write...
    raw.wirte...
    // don't worry be happy, woo~ hoo~ hoo~
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I learned that you can't..

Some related links here: http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~parrt/course/601/lectures/io.html
and here: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/bufferedwriter.html

Comment: (1) A `RandomAccessFile` is not an `OutputStream` or `Writer`, and thus can not be wrapped with a BufferedAnything.  (2) The very goal is to *stop* buffering, not add it.

Comment: @cHao - Cool, thanks a lot. I'm heading back to the books then!