# Does RandomAccessFile#close() sync written data to disk?

Tags: java, randomaccessfile

I just stopped by a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7550190/330457) about this subject.

Say when I do like this. (Note that I used `"rw"` not `"rws"` or `"rwd"`).

```java
try(RandomAccessFile raw = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw")) {
    // write some
}
```

Does `RandomAccessFile#close()` do as if I explicitly do `getFD().sync()`?

```java
try(RandomAccessFile raw = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw")) {
    // write some
    raw.getFD().sync();
}
```

I searched `RandomAccessFile.java` and the source just do

```java
public void close() throws IOException {
    // doin' here, things look like irrelevant
    close0();
}

private native void close0() throws IOException;
```

Comment: Yes and no. Eventually the data will get to disk. But no, there is absolutely no guarantee of when that happens. Not when close returns, not even when the JVM exits. But probably almost certainly most of the time very soon after close is called.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Interesting. Is that fact should lead me to call `getFD().sync()` explicitly?